# react app loading asset from incorrect file path when accessed from nested route

Tags: reactjs

My app is structured like this:

```
src
 assets
  corpse.png
 components
  Books.js
  Corpse.js
```

In both **Books.js** and **Corpse.js** is the following line: `import CorpseImage from 'assets/corpse.png'`. This image loads only on **Books.js** and is broken on the latter. Inspecting the img filepath shows what is happening, but I'm unsure why.

**Books.js** img filepath: /static/media/corpse.2a3d71bf.png

**Corpse.js** img filepath: /books/static/media/corpse.2a3d71bf.png

**App.js** looks like this:

```
<Route exact path='/books/' component={Books} />
<Route path='/books/corpse' component={Corpse} />
```

I have the src set in the root my **jsconfig.json**:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
 "baseUrl": "src"
},
 "include": ["src"]
}
```

How can I import assets into the `/books/corpse` subpath?

Comment: i believe i am using relative import? base url is `src`

Comment: The recommended way is to use import. See the [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/#when-to-use-the-public-folder).

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the relative paths to import images:

```
import CorpseImage from '../assets/corpse.png'
```

in both the `Books.js` and `Corpse.js` components.

Assuming that the directory structure is like:

```
src
 assets
  corpse.png
 components
  Books.js
  Corpse.js
```

Here is the [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/).

Comment: This is definitely the recommended way to do it, but I'm still unsure as to why accessing the image from a nested url causes it insert part of the current url into the img src. Again, note that the image works on the `/books` page (and links to `/static/media/corpse.2a3d71bf.png`, which exists) but does not work on the `/books/corpse` page (which links to `/books/static/media/corpse.2a3d71bf.png`, and which does not exist)

Comment: If it is still not working for you. Consider creating a sandbox so that we can find the real issue.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a better way is to use a `public` folder instead of importing the images. If you are using create-react-app, create a public/assets folder and load all the images inside.

You can then use the following directly without importing.

```
<img src="/assets/corpse.png" />
```

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

anything that is created in public (including index.html), is internet/publicly accessible via the url (e.g. http://localhost / http://www.example.com ), anything else will have to be compiled, and bundled in to the respective JS files.

Images is a little different.

> importing a file gives you a string value. This value is the final
> path you can reference in your code, e.g. as the src attribute of an
> image or the href of a link to a PDF.

In your example, you though putting baseUrl means it will automatically be just absolute `/assets/*.jpg` but **no**, what is does is it actually creates a './assets/corpse.png' string, which is relative to the JS file it's created.

Hence in your /books/corpse path, ./assets/corpse.png's absolute path becomes /books/assets/corpse, and once it's compiled, it will move to static folder, hence /books/assets/corpse.

If you use CRA, I believe it adds imported images to static folder hence it becomes /books/static/assets/corpse.

Comment: is there any reason why using images directly like that would make it so they don't load? if i import the same file it works, but using directly is broken image